# PHP работа с картинками

Tags: php

Добрый день, подскажите есть ли способ обрабатывать изображения как будто они нарисованные, как это делает приложение prisma?
https://prisma-ai.com/

Может быть существует сторонний сервис,куда можно отправлять методами PHP  изображение и получать обработанное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может вам нужен `imagefilter()`? Он позволяет задавать оттенки к изображению, может изменять яркость, контрастность, добавлять размытие. Можно использовать и похожие библиотеки, с более расширенным функционалом: **ImageMagick** и **Gmagick**.
**Prisma**, на сколько я знаю, работает с помощью нейросети, то есть, если по простому, рисует новое изображение по принципу старого, добавляя необходимый фильтр. Как по мне, делать подобное на **PHP**, не самая лучшая идея. Лучше использовать **Python** или другие языки.
Если я где-то не прав, просьба поправить.

Comment: Питон? (rofl) В целом, поддерживаю идею)